# Comparing BigDecimal and int in Java

Tags: java, comparison, int, bigdecimal

Which one is the best way of comparing a BigDecimal and an int in Java : coverting the BigDecimal to int or converting int to BigDecimal ?

Comment: If you convert the BigDecimal to int, you are liable to exceed its range.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you expect the `BigDecimal` value to be really big (i.e. outside the range of `int` values, which is -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1) and/or to contain decimal digits, or simply want to play safe, you should convert the `int` to `BigDecimal` to avoid overflow / truncation errors.

Otherwise, if performance is a really big issue (which is rare), it *might* be better the other way around.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to know ! Thanks @peter !

Answer (score 2):

You want to convert the `int` to a `BigDecimal`.

This is because you won't always be able to convert a BigDecimal to an int; you'll lose any information after the decimal point and the value of the BigDecimal might be outside the range of an int.

Answer (score 1):

As `BigDecimal` extends the range of `int` you will have to convert the `int` into `BigDecimal` to be sure they can be compared, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

One reason not to convert int to BigDecimal is the fact that you would be creating a new object, therefore you are really throwing garbage on your heap to perform equality.
Also, primitive equality would be faster than the one on the actual BigInteger object as well.

Comment: Why would this be "throwing garbage on the heap"?

Comment: but this might couse a overflow and the result might be wrong. If BigDecimal bd = maxint +1 and bd are converted to int the result will be 1

Comment: Sure, it depends on the actual use Case. @Oli each time for the comparison case you would create a new BigInteger object, which might not be necessary and which resides on the heap, instead of taking the actual primitive value already stored within the BigInt object itself